# Leer las columnas de una tabla HTML de tamaño variable

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Quiero leer una serie de tablas HTML que tienen tamaño variable. Obtengo el head y almaceno sin problema el número de columnas que va a tener.

Ahora quiero dinamizar la lectura de las columnas, y necesito saber cómo automatizo este proceso, para no hacer:

```
foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]') as $element)
{
    echo  $element;
    foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]') as $element2)
    {
        foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]') as $element3)
        {
            foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]') as $element4)
            {
                foreach($html->find('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]') as $element5)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo  $element2;
    echo  $element3;
    echo  $element4;
    echo  $element5;
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es `$html`, un documento de Simple HTML?

Comment: $html es el file_get_html de una de las urls que intervienen

Comment: entonces supongo que sí, que es utilizando Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Comment: Es la librería que estoy usando para esa parte, ¿me puedes poner un ejemplo?